# Unit test Global filters in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, global-filter

I have a MVC4 application and adding bunch of global filters in global.asax. They need to be in one order. I want to write a unit test to make sure they are always in the desired order. Is there a way to access all global filters or test this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You register the global filters in `FilterConfig` by default (under App_Start), right? This is something like this:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }
}
```

You can then call this method from a test case and pass a `GlobalFilterCollection` instance and after that you can test the order of the `GlobalFilterCollection` you passed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a specific order, you can even specify an order as an attribute

e.g. [FilterName(Order = 1)]

By default, the filters do not have any order specified and hence they are executed randomly by the framework.

Anything with Order> -1 ensures the order in which the filters are to be executed.

(Not sure if this helps in providing more info, I thought it would be more useful)

References:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filter(v=vs.118).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filter.order(v=vs.118).aspx